How to get fields names that were chosen with method "only()"?
For example, I have simple model:
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField("id", primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    age = models.IntegerField()

I use method only to choose fields I need:
queryset = Person.objects.all().only("first_name", "age")

How can I get fields names("first_name", "age") that were chosen?
I tried this:
queryset.query.get_loaded_field_names()
But I got this error:
AttributeError:'Query' object has no attribute 'get_loaded_field_names'

You can use the .get_select_mask() method of the .query object:
queryset.query.get_select_mask()
This will return a dictionary where the keys are field objects, so you can get the name of the fields with:
[f.name for f in queryset.query.get_select_mask()]
This is however not a good idea from a software engineering perspective: the entire idea is that .only(…) [Django-doc] and .defer(…) [Django-doc] are used in a transparent manner.

Thank you, for the answer. That's what i need. I'm writing a test, that checks if I chose only necessary fields.

Can you tell me, what means .only() and .defer() are used in a transparent manner, please?

@Tarasyonok: that the core idea is that you typically don't need to know what is defered and what is not.
